# Compress all files in a folder with python?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

this code takes a bunch of files in a folder (based on the file name), zips them into bz2 and adds them into a tar file. Is there a way I can modify this to only compress the files into bz2 (or gzip)? I do not want to have to deal with having them packaged into a tar. I just want to go through each file in a directory and compress it.

```
import os
from glob import glob
import tarfile

os.chdir(r'C:\Documents\FTP\\')
compression = "w:bz2"
extension = '.tar.bz2'

filename = 'survey_'
filetype = 'survey_report_*.csv'
tarname = saveloc+filename+extension
files = glob(filetype)
tar = tarfile.open(tarname, compression)
for file in files:
    if file not in tarname:
        print('Packaging file:', file)
        tar.add(file)
tar.close()
```

EDIT:

This code seems to work for some files, but for other ones it makes them 1kb and when I open it there are just some random characters. Any suggestions?

---

```
import bz2
import os

location = r'C:\Users\Documents\FTP\\'
os.chdir(location)
filelist = os.listdir(location)
for file in filelist:
    data = open(file).read()
    try:
        output = bz2.BZ2File(file + '.bz2', 'wb')
        output.write(data)
    finally:
        output.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with the bz2 module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html ?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. My goal is to compress each file individually so I can read it in pandas later. I don't want to create a packaged folder or archive. Will that work for my purposes?

Comment: Have you even looked at the documentation for the module?

Comment: I reviewed this https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html, however, it does not show me any examples. I don't really have a strong grasp on Python yet.. I only know Pandas for munging data and doing analysis (the examples on the Pandas documentation are very clear, it shows exactly what will be output so it's easy to adapt to your own data). It's hard for me to interpret.

Comment: I googled "python bz2 module tutorial" and this was the first result. https://pymotw.com/2/bz2/#writing-compressed-files

Comment: thanks I used that and was able to come up with a revised script which worked for my larger files, but then for small files (like 40kb) it reduced them to 1kb with random characters, pasted my code above

Comment: It might be worth posting a new question with only the updated code, and a minimal example of a file that you think isn't compressing correctly, so that others can try to reproduce your problem.